# Squash commits in a branch which contains multiple commits

Tags: git, android-studio

I have created a branch from master branch and have made multiple commits in it and pushed it.. Meanwhile, when any new changes available in the master branch, I pulled and merged the changes from Master branch and made my changes on top of it and pushed new commits.

I have my 4 commits in my branch but have several other commits in between which .. at around 45..

Now I want to squash all my changes and push into one commit. Any idea how this can be achieved.

What I did:

1. Moved to my branch 
   git checkout mybranch
2. git rebase -i HEAD~49
3. This doesn't had my all changes

Any idea where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you show the commit graph? I don't quite understand your situation.